# What were C.S Peirce's contributions to theory of relations?

Tags: biographical-details, philosophy-of-science, mathematical-logic

In my study of Peirce I came across a number statements that he extended De Morgan's relation algebra.
What exactly are his contributions to relation algebra?

Comment: See [C.S. Peirce’s Logic of Relations:](https://www.uni-log.org/ULS6-peirce.html) and [Peirce’s Deductive Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/peirce-logic/) and D.Merrill, [DeMorgan, Peirce and the Logic of Relations](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40319851?seq=1)

Comment: And see Charles Sanders Peirce, [Description of a Notation for the Logic of Relatives, resulting from an Amplification of the Conceptions (1870)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/25058006.pdf)

Comment: Maybe useful D.Merrill, [Augustus De Morgan and the Logic of Relations (1990)](https://books.google.it/books?id=c1mVBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)